# I need to know about the below kube_state_metrics description. Exactly looking is what the particular metrics doing

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I need to know about the below kube_state_metrics description. Exactly looking is what the particular metrics doing.

```
Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Metrics:
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_labels
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_metadata_generation
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_min_replicas
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_target_metric
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_status_condition
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_status_current_replicas
kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_status_desired_replicas

Job Metrics:
kube_job_owner

Namespace Metrics:
kube_namespace_status_condition

Node Metrics:
kube_node_role
kube_node_status_capacity
kube_node_status_allocatable

PersistentVolumeClaim Metrics:
kube_persistentvolumeclaim_access_mode
kube_persistentvolumeclaim_status_condition

PersistentVolume Metrics:
kube_persistentvolume_capacity_bytes

Pod Metrics:
kube_pod_restart_policy
kube_pod_init_container_info
kube_pod_init_container_status_waiting_reason
kube_pod_init_container_status_terminated_reason
kube_pod_init_container_status_last_terminated_reason
kube_pod_init_container_resource_limits

ReplicaSet metrics:
kube_replicaset_labels

Service Metrics:
kube_statefulset_status_current_revision
kube_statefulset_status_update_revision


StorageClass Metrics:
kube_storageclass_info
kube_storageclass_labels
kube_storageclass_created

ValidatingWebhookConfiguration Metrics:
kube_validatingwebhookconfiguration_info
kube_validatingwebhookconfiguration_created
kube_validatingwebhookconfiguration_metadata_resource_version


Vertical Pod Autoscaler Metrics:
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_spec_resourcepolicy_container_policies_minallowed
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_spec_resourcepolicy_container_policies_maxallowed
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_status_recommendation_containerrecommendations_lowerbound
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_status_recommendation_containerrecommendations_target
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_status_recommendation_containerrecommendations_uncappedtarget
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_status_recommendation_containerrecommendations_upperbound
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_labels
kube_verticalpodautoscaler_spec_updatepolicy_updatemode

volumeattachment-metrics:
kube_volumeattachment_info
kube_volumeattachment_created
kube_volumeattachment_labels
kube_volumeattachment_spec_source_persistentvolume
kube_volumeattachment_status_attached
kube_volumeattachment_status_attachment_metadata


CertificateSigningRequest Metrics:
kube_certificatesigningrequest_created
kube_certificatesigningrequest_condition
kube_certificatesigningrequest_labels
kube_certificatesigningrequest_cert_length
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with [the documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) where you can find the list of [Exposed Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/docs#exposed-metrics):

- CertificateSigningRequest Metrics
- ConfigMap Metrics
- CronJob Metrics
- DaemonSet Metrics
- Deployment Metrics
- Endpoint Metrics
- Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Metrics
- Ingress Metrics
- Job Metrics
- Lease Metrics
- LimitRange Metrics
- MutatingWebhookConfiguration Metrics
- Namespace Metrics
- NetworkPolicy Metrics
- Node Metrics
- PersistentVolume Metrics
- PersistentVolumeClaim Metrics
- Pod Disruption Budget Metrics
- Pod Metrics
- ReplicaSet Metrics
- ReplicationController Metrics
- ResourceQuota Metrics
- Secret Metrics
- Service Metrics
- StatefulSet Metrics
- StorageClass Metrics
- ValidatingWebhookConfiguration Metrics
- VerticalPodAutoscaler Metrics
- VolumeAttachment Metrics

There you will find all the necessary info and descriptions you are looking for. Also I recommend reading [this blog](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-6-kube-state-metrics-14f4e7c8710b) to get a better understanding of how they work.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I know the metrics. But i need to know about the each metrics definition What i mentioned in the post. Can you help on this. I am getting only metrics name not the definition.

Comment: @SibiPrasanth More details can be found within the particular links. Not all of them have definitions/examples but all got listed value types, labels/tags and status which will help you understand them better. Please let me know if that helped.